# extract after last instance of a character but only if extracted text is 4 or less characters

Tags: excel

I am struggling with finding a specified extension inside a name column.

example data:

1. abc.jpg
2. abc.jpeg
3. abc.abc.pdf
4. abc.abc.abcdf

I would like to show only:

1. jpg
2. jpeg
3. pdf

So basically I found out a formula which is extracting everything after the last occurrence of a specified character (in this example it is a '.') which looks like:

=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A1))),LEN(A1)))

but using this I have output :

1. jpg
2. jpeg
3. pdf
4. abcdf

How I can limit this to extract only 'extensions'? My idea is to make it 'show only if it is 4 or fewer characters).

Thanks

Comment: How are you defining a valid extension? So if a file has an extension of abcd, that's ok but abcdf is not? I would just keep your formula as-is and perhaps throw a warning if you believe it's not a true extension.

Comment: hey, thanks for the reply! The point is I actually can't define a valid one (or I don't know how) so I can assume 4 characters or less is fine (most extensions are like xlsx, pdf, jpg, jpeg etc) because I have a lot of results which have more than 5 characters after last '.' and I don't want to display them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the data can also include occasions without a dot, then here's one solution.

Cell B2 formula:

```
=IF(AND(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(".",A2)),LEN(TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))))<5),TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A2,".",REPT(" ",LEN(A2))),LEN(A2))),"invalid")
```

Drag it down. It's first checking if 2 conditions are true:

1. There's a dot in the name.
2. The "extension" is less than 5 characters long.

If both are true, then it's returning the extension. Otherwise, show "invalid".

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for!! Thank you m8 (I can't vote up your solution coz less than 15 rep but this is perfect for me)! Really helpful!